# How to show Term ID beside Name Category with wp_dropdown_categories()

Tags: customization, wp-admin

I have example code:

```
                        <?php 
                                $defaults = array(
                                    'show_option_all'   => '',
                                    'show_option_none'  => '',
                                    'orderby'           => 'id',
                                    'order'             => 'ASC',
                                    'show_count'        => 1,
                                    'hide_empty'        => 0,
                                    'child_of'          => 0,
                                    'exclude'           => '',
                                    'echo'              => 1,
                                    'selected'          => 1,
                                    'hierarchical'      => 1,
                                    'name'              => 'cat',
                                    'id'                => 'mySelect',
                                    'class'             => 'postform',
                                    'depth'             => 0,
                                    'tab_index'         => 1,
                                    'taxonomy'          => 'category',
                                    'hide_if_empty'     => false,
                                    'option_none_value' => -1,
                                    'value_field'       => 'name',
                                    'required'          => false,
                                );
                                wp_dropdown_categories( $defaults )
                        ?>
```

Html will have like this:

```
<option class="level-1" value="Name category 1">Name category 1 (38)</option>
```

How to show term ID beside Name category like this:

```
<option class="level-1" value="Name category 1">Name category 1 (ID-161) (38)</option>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom hook to the functions.php for that:

```
function my_add_cat_id($category_name, $category) {
    return $category_name ." (ID-".$category->term_id.")";
}
add_filter('list_cats', 'my_add_cat_id', 10,2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It work for me. Thank you again!